# IFFT of Hermitian matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I read in a [paper](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/netmit/wordpress/projects/spectrum-usage-coverage-data-rates/pixnet/) the IFFT of a Hermitian matrix is a matrix of all reals. But I'm not able to reproduce this in Python using numpy.

```
# Hermitian matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix
m = [[2     , 2 + 1j, 4      ],
     [2 - 1j, 3     , 0  + 1j],
     [4     , 0 - 1j, 1      ]]
m = numpy.matrix(m)
im = numpy.fft.ifft2(m)
print im
```

This gives the following which is not just reals:

```
[[ 2.00000000+0.j         0.42955838-0.16666667j  0.23710829-0.16666667j]
[ 0.23710829+0.16666667j -0.66666667-0.57735027j  0.38490018+0.j        ]
[ 0.42955838+0.16666667j -0.38490018+0.j         -0.66666667+0.57735027j]]
```

Is my understanding of Hermitian matrices off? Or am I using numpy wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I think the paper referred to something slightly different.  A Hermitian matrix is one that that's equal to its complex conjugate transpose.  However, the `fft` of real input is "Hermite-symmetric".  It's equal to its complex conjugate, but not its complex conjugate transpose.

On a side note, I may be getting the terms a bit confused, as the only time I've ever heard of a "hermite-symmetric" matrix is in the context of the fft of real values.  Nonetheless, I'm 90% sure this is what the paper was referring to.

You do indeed have a Hermitian matrix as input:

```
In [4]: np.allclose(m, np.conj(m).T)
Out[4]: True
```

But it's not "hermite-symmetric":

```
In [5]: np.allclose(m, np.conj(m))
Out[5]: False
```

---

However, let's look at what happens when we take the fft of real values:

```
In [6]: data = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)

In [7]: result = np.fft.fft2(data)
```

Notice that the resulting fft is (almost) identical to its complex conjugate (There's a difference in the sign of one term that I don't understand.  I'd appreciate an explanation, if anyone knows!):

```
In [8]: result
Out[8]: 
array([[ 36.0+0.j ,  -4.5+2.6j,  -4.5-2.6j],
       [-13.5+7.8j,   0.0+0.j ,   0.0+0.j ],
       [-13.5-7.8j,   0.0+0.j ,   0.0+0.j ]])

In [9]: np.conj(result)
Out[9]: 
array([[ 36.0-0.j ,  -4.5-2.6j,  -4.5+2.6j],
       [-13.5-7.8j,   0.0-0.j ,   0.0-0.j ],
       [-13.5+7.8j,   0.0-0.j ,   0.0-0.j ]])
```

But it's not Hermitian, as it's not equal to its complex conjugate transpose:

```
In [10]: np.conj(result).T
Out[10]: 
array([[ 36.0-0.j , -13.5-7.8j, -13.5+7.8j],
       [ -4.5-2.6j,   0.0-0.j ,   0.0-0.j ],
       [ -4.5+2.6j,   0.0-0.j ,   0.0-0.j ]])
```

At any rate, this may not be the full answer, but hopefully it moves you a step in the right direction.

In practice, if you're working with real input, and  you'd like to only get real output, use [`np.fft.rfft`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html#numpy.fft.rfft) and [`np.fft.irff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.irfft.html) (and the `irfft2` version, in this 2D case). Similarly, have a look at `eigh` and `eigvalsh` when you're calculating the eigenvalues/vectors of a Hermitian matrix and want only real output.

---

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is it possible to have a 2D matrix of complex numbers that is Hermite-symmetric? I can make one that's Hermitian, which follows the definition in the paper, but it doesn't have this nice property with the ifft giving only real values.

Comment: I'm also not seeing the sign difference you mentioned. The matrices in Out[8] and Out[9] all look the same to me in values and the sign of the real components.

Comment: `np.allclose(m, np.conj(m))` is not a test for hermitian symmetry, it's a test for real-valuedness. The only way that `imag(m)` and `imag(conj(m))` are equal is if they're zero. The symmetry here refers to the FFT result at frequency `k` and `-k`: `m[k]==conj(m[N-k])`, with `N` being the length of `m` and `0<=k<N`. For 2D FFTs the result is a bit more complex.

Answer (score 0):

As @Joe said, the "Hermitian matrix" mentioned in the paper might not be the same one that is known as common.

I found that the paper actually uses the term "Hermitian function",

[image: paper]

which is defined as

[image: explanation].

As a matter of fact, this is a definition of the Hermitian symmetry. You could get some knowledge about what is Hermitian symmetry from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74265597/8561448) I wrote under another question.

If you want the IFFT result to be all real, the input you give should satisfy the Hermitian symmetry.

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Discrete_Fourier_transform&oldid=1117538153#The_real-input_multidimensional_DFT), we say a 2D matrix is Hermitian-symmetric when **`X(k1, k2) = conj(X(N1-k1,N2-k2)`**.

```py
[[X(0, 0), X(0, 1), X(0, 2)],
 [X(1, 0), X(1, 1), X(1, 2)],
 [X(2, 0), X(2, 1), X(2, 2)]]
=
[[conj(X(3, 3)), conj(X(3, 2)), conj(X(3, 1))],
 [conj(X(2, 3)), conj(X(2, 2)), conj(X(2, 1))],
 [conj(X(1, 3)), conj(X(1, 2)), conj(X(1, 1))]]  # Hermitian-symmetric
=
[[conj(X(0, 0)), conj(X(0, 2)), conj(X(0, 1))],
 [conj(X(2, 0)), conj(X(2, 2)), conj(X(2, 1))],
 [conj(X(1, 0)), conj(X(1, 2)), conj(X(1, 1))]] # mod 3
```

A verification could be done by replacing the above `X` matrix with the `result` matrix from @Joe's example.