# is a numpy FFT on real values actually hermitian?

Tags: python, numpy, math, fft

I am a bit confused on the symmetry of the output of np.fft.fftn(). According to [Numpy's FFT page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.fft.html#real-and-hermitian-transforms), if the input array is real, then the output is Hermitian. According to that page, this means that "the component at frequency *f<sub>k</sub>* is the complex conjugate of the component at frequency *-f<sub>k</sub>* ."  However, [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix) says that a Hermitian matrix is equal to its conjugate transpose, which is not quite the same thing. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32405067/2836338) seems to have a similar question (with code), so maybe it's just semantics (hence my question title). I'm ultimately looking to understand how to ensure a positive transform, which requires the input to be positive definite, which requires the input to first be Hermitian. So in my case semantics is important, i.e. is the result of numpy fft on a real array actually Hermitian (for the purposes of ensuring positive definite input)?

Comment: I dunno about the use of the term Hermitian here; it doesn't seem conventional to talk about the output being Hermitian, but rather, from what I've seen, to talk about the operator being Hermitian. I suppose that's a question for math.stackexchange.com. Anyway I suppose that the point they're trying to make in the Numpy documentation is that for real inputs, any complex numbers in the output appear as conjugate pairs.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your goal of ensuring positive outputs. The Fourier transform is a linear transform, so it's output is unbounded. Are you constructing a quadratic form `x' . A . x` where `A` is the Fourier transform and `x` is a real input? Sorry I can't be more helpful, it sounds interesting but I am not sure what's going on. I apologize for my own confusion.

Comment: No, I'm simply taking the fft of real input, and I would like the output to be positive (I can modify my input). From what I have read online (e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194107/conditions-for-positivity-of-fourier-transform), based on Bocher's theorem if my input array is positive definite, then the output of my FFT will be positive. But I might have some terms mixed up here, so I'm trying to figure out if the fft from numpy is actually hermitian first. So perhaps your distinction between the output vs the operator being hermitian is an important point I'm missing.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean, sorry about that. My advice is to take it to math.stackexchange.com because it's not about Numpy in particular, it's a property all FFT implementations will share. I'm not sure the linked-to mathoverflow question is relevant, because it's about the continuous FT, but maybe the properties of interest carry over to the discrete FT. If you repost your question there, my advice is to give some context about the larger goal you're working towards, or for what reason you are looking for this property.

Comment: Okay I'll do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR:  The result of numpy fft on a real array is not Hermitian.

The correct statement would be

> *the result of numpy fft on a real array is **Hermitian-symmetric***.

### Before Answering

On the page you mentioned [1], I found more information about what is "Hermitian" [2].
In numpy's context, when a signal is called "Hermitian", it has Hermitian symmetry.

The term "Hermitian" is confusing, because when I Googled it, I mostly found explanations about the "Hermitian Matrix" [3]. And that why the misunderstandings occur.

I wrote the original answer in my local editor (vscode) with latex support. However, stackoverflow was unable to render latex in markdown, which is why I posted all the formulas as images.

### What is Hermitian-symmetry?

So you might ask, what on earth is Hermitian-symmetry? Well, I found three definition on the internet.

#### Def.1. via [numpy.fft.rfft](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html#numpy.fft.rfft)

> When the DFT is computed for purely real input, the output is Hermitian-symmetric, **i.e. the negative frequency terms are just the complex conjugates of the corresponding positive-frequency terms**, and the negative-frequency terms are therefore redundant.

#### Def.2. via [wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Discrete_Fourier_transform&oldid=1117538153#DFT_of_real_and_purely_imaginary_signals)

[image: def-2]

#### Def.3. via [stanford.edu](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/ReviewFourier/Symmetries_Real_Signals.html)

[image: def-3]

The first definition is more difficult to understand because what are negative and positive frequency are not stated.

Def. 2. and 3. are basically saying the same thing, but 2. give you a concise equation while 3. discusses the property of DFT signal in terms of real and imaginary components. Note that the symbol used in Def. 2. and 3. are slightly different.

### Why does the real signal's DFT have Hermitian symmetry?

Taken from book [4], I will now provide you with an derivation about the Hermitian symmetry of the DFT of real signals.

Note that the notation I use is consistent with Def. 3..

#### Derivation

[image: deriviation]

It can be seen that E.q.1 & E.q.2 agree with Def.3, while E.q.3 is the same as Def.2..

### Some Properties

Some properties could be deduced from the real signal's DFT thanks to its Hermitian symmetry.
[image: properties]

The E.q.4 explains periodicity, while the E.q.5 provides a practical form of Hermitian-symmetry when input real signals are limited sequence.

What's more, the first and middle element of real signal's DFT are both real numbers.

### Example

Here is an example showing the DFT result of a sequence of real numbers.

```py
In : np.fft.fft([2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 3])
Out: array([13.+0.j,  1.-2.j,  1.+4.j,  1.+2.j, -3.+0.j,  1.-2.j,  1.-4.j,  1.+2.j])
```

### Conclusion

A benifit of real input's Hermitian-symmetry is that, when computing the DFT (or, in practice, FFT), numpy (and pytorch) will omit the `transformed_array[N//2+1:]` part due to the redundancy. This feature is described in [np.fft.rfft](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html#).

### Reference

[1] https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.fft.html#real-and-hermitian-transforms

[2] https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.fft.html#hermitian-ffts

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix

[4] 郑君里, 应启珩, and 杨为理, 信号与系统（下册）. 高等教育出版社 第三版, 2011.

Comment: Impressive answer. Unfortunately it belongs on math.SE or maybe DSP.SE, not on SO. That there is no latex support here is a good hint that your answer doesn't belong here. SO is for questions and answers about programming, not about math or DFT properties. I don't intend to be mean with this comment, I am trying to save you from this type of effort in the future, and I'm hoping this answer doesn't go to waste!

Comment: You are right, I also realized that SO might not be the place of posting math when I struggled with editing math formula on it. However, I am much more an SOer than a math.SEer, etc, since I am more a programmer. I made this effort just to give somebody who is also confused by torch/numpy.fft.fft a little help. Maybe next time I should answer the related question on math.SE and paste the link here. Or maybe I could keep expecting that SO will support latex one day.